# How to use JSoup to navigate pages

Tags: java, android, post, jsoup

I'm working on an android app which parses an html page and uses its elements and then goes to the next page and extracts its elements. I was previously doing this work with Selenium but when I use it with Android it uses way too much memory and the app stops responding. Now I'm stuck at the login page where I have to enter the username and password. I manage to do that but I'm not able to go to the next page. It returns me the same login page and not the next one. I really need to do this with JSoup because eventually the code has to be integrated with the android app code. Help please!

```
 try {


        String url = "http://slateisb.nu.edu.pk/portal";
        Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url).
                followRedirects(true).
                data("eid", "i110013").
                data("pw", "001").
                method(Method.POST).get();
        String title = doc.title();
        print("Title : %s" , title);

    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Two shots in the dark: set a user-agent mimicking a browser; fetch the login page first and pass any cookies the server set on your login request.  (Also, if those are your username and password you may wish to edit them out and flag a moderator to redact the old revision.)

Comment: I am new to JSoup, please elaborate..

Comment: [Cookbook example that sets the user-agent](http://jsoup.org/cookbook/input/load-document-from-url) (you may want to use a full browser's user-agent, not just "Mozilla").  Get cookies from a Connection.Response with the [cookie(String)](http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/Connection.Base.html#cookie%28java.lang.String%29) method and set them with the cookie(String, String) method on Connection.  That should be enough pointers for you to work out the rest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import java.util.Map;

import org.jsoup.Connection;
import org.jsoup.Connection.Method;
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            //In this url you must login
            String loginUrl = "http://slateisb.nu.edu.pk/portal/xlogin";

            //This is an example, it can be anything else
            String url = "http://slateisb.nu.edu.pk/portal";

            //First login. Take the cookies
            Connection.Response res = Jsoup
                    .connect(loginUrl)
                    .data("eid", "i110013")
                    .data("pw", "001")
                    .referrer("http://www.google.com")
                    .userAgent(
                            "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; WindowsNT 5.1; en-US; rv1.8.1.6) Gecko/20070725 Firefox/2.0.0.6")
                    .method(Method.POST).timeout(0).execute();

            Map<String, String> loginCookies = res.cookies();

            //Now you can parse any page you want, as long as you pass the cookies
            Document doc = Jsoup
                    .connect(url)
                    .timeout(0)
                    .cookies(loginCookies)
                    .referrer("http://www.google.com")
                    .userAgent(
                            "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; WindowsNT 5.1; en-US; rv1.8.1.6) Gecko/20070725 Firefox/2.0.0.6")
                    .get();

            System.out.println("Title : " + doc.title());

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Works perfectly, thank you so much! Question. What does the userAgent do? And will it work on Android too?

Comment: Yes it will. Every browser sends headers that identify it. So when you are visiting/parsing a page by a bot (machine) you have to imitate the same behavor because some servers don't permit the absence of those headers.